# How to update module on generating services in angular8 in angular cli?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-services

I am trying to generate the services and update app modules in cli.
My question is in `angular 5.2` and `angular-cli-1.7.2` i was using

```
ng g service test -m app.module
```

But in angular 8 and angular-cli 8 I checked the documentation there is no option for the app module update from cli. 
I can do it manually in `app.module`. But though to double check is there any option in cli.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It has been removed since angular 6, as the recommended way now is via providing a singleton service. https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
```